# How to search same data on two different tables with same column names

Tags: sql, database, search

I have two tables with different names but similar schema and different data on them. I would like to search for certain data on both tables and combine the results.

for example:

Table A:
time, brand, model, color, engine_type

Table B:
time, brand, model, color, engine_model

*engine_type* and *engine_model* has the same data in reality, but column name's are different

I would like to search certain *engine_type* or *engine_model* on both tables and show results. How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a union query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE engine_type = 'some value'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE engine_model = 'some value';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union` if you dont want duplicate data as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM TableA 
UNION
SELECT * FROM TableB) t
WHERE engine_type = 'some value';
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM Table A

INTERSECT

SELECT * FROM TABLE B
```

THIS CODE GIVES YOU ROWS WITH COMMON DATA IN BOTH COLUMNS